# Explicit construction of a nested local base in the weak*-topology

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras

Consider the $C^*$-algebra $C([a,b])$ of complex continuous functions in a closed interval of $\mathbb{R}$. I want to construct a countable nested local base in the state space of the algebra with respect to the $weak*$-topology. Such a base exists since the algebra is separable. How can we construct it explicitly?

Comment: Do you mean a nested **neighborhood** base?  The separability of the space is enough to get this if you restrict the weak$^*$ topology to a bounded subset of the dual space $C([a, b])'$.  Oterwise the statement is false.

Comment: @Ruy Yes,  it s the same. See for example:  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LocalBase.html Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theorem**.  Let $X$ be a normed space.

1. If the algebraic dimension of $X$ is  uncountable then the origin of the dual space $X'$ does not admit a countable
   neighborhood base relative to the weak$^*$ topology.
2. If $X$ is separable then every bounded subset of $X'$ is metrizable relative to the weak$^*$ topology.

*Proof*.  (1) Suppose by contradiction that $\{V_n\}_n$ is a countable neighborhood base of the origin.  By definition of
the weak$^*$ topology,  for each $n$  there is a finite set $F_n\subseteq X$, and a positive number $\varepsilon _n$,  such that the set
$$
  U(F_n, \varepsilon _n):= \{f\in  X': |f(x)|<\varepsilon _n,  \forall  x\in  F_n\}
  $$
is contained in $V_n$.

By hypothesis we have that
$$
  \text{span}\left(\bigcup_nF_n\right) \subsetneq X,
  $$
so we may pick some vector $y$ in $X$
not lying in the linear span of  $\bigcup_nF_n$.  Observing that
$U(\{y\},1)$ is a neighborhood of the origin in $X'$, we will reach a contradiction by proving that
$$
  V_n\not\subseteq U(G,1),
  $$
for any given $n$.  In fact, since $y\notin \text{span}(F_n)$, we may use Hahn-Banach to produce a continuous linear
functional $f$ on $X$ vanishing on $F_n$, and such that $f(y)=1$.    It then follows that any multiple of $f$ lies in
$U(F_n, \varepsilon _n)$, and hence also in
$V_n$, but $\lambda f$ is not in $U(G,1)$ if $|\lambda |\geq 1$.

(2)  Assuming that $X$ is separable,
choose a dense subset  $\{x_n\}_n$ of the unit ball of $X$.  Given any $f$ and $g$ in $X'$, define
$$
  d(f,g) = \sum_n 2^{-n}\min\{1,  |f(x_n)-g(x_n)|\}.
  $$
It is easy to see that $d$ is a metric on $X'$ and moreover that a net $\{f_i\}_i$ converges to some $f$ according to
this metric iff
$$
  f_i(x_n)\ {\buildrel i\to\infty \over \longrightarrow}\ f(x_n),\quad\forall n.
  \tag 1
  $$

On the other hand,  it is well known that a *bounded* net $\{f_i\}_i$ converges to  $f$ in the weak$^*$ topology iff (1)
holds.

So if $S$ is a bounded subset of $X'$, the nets within  $S$ converge weak$^*$ iff they converge according to $d$,
thus proving that the weak$^*$ topology on $S$ is metrizable by $d$.
QED

---

It is well known that the algebraic dimension of any infinite dimension Banach space  is uncountable,  so the Theorem
above applies to $C([0, 1])$ and hence the origin in $C([0, 1])'$ does not admit a countable neighborhood base relative
to the weak$^*$ topology.

On the other hand, the state space of  $C([0, 1])$ is a bounded set, so part (2) of the above Theorem applies.

Comment: Thank  you, for the theorem! You are right. What if we focus on states on C* algebra (positive normalized functionals). The state space satisfies the requirement of compactness relative to the weak*-topology. And there is a local base. How could I construct it explicitly?

Comment: Question changed to comply with Ruy's answer.

Comment: @val, As I said in my first comment, what you want is true on bounded sets. I have thus updated my answer according to  the new form of your question.  Let me know if you think this is OK.

Comment: Thank your so much for your reply. Part (2) of the theorem applies to the state space of the algebra. In addition you provided a metric so that I can now define a countable local base at each point in the state space.

Comment: I was thinking that, in addition to balls of radius $1/n$, one could also take for a nbd basis of a state $f$, the sets $$V_n =\{g\in S: |g(x_i)-f(x_i)|<1/n, \forall i\leq n\}.$$ I suppose it is not hard to show that every ball around $f$ contains one of these, so they in fact form a nbd basis.

Comment: To be honest, I am trying to prove that Vn is an nbd basis and  I cannot. If you could give another hand I would appreciate it. In any case I am grateful for your help